# How to delete rows within a time frame (date&time format, but I want to only keep rows between certain hours)

Tags: excel, vba

I have 55437 rows of data.

[image: Screenshot of first few rows of data]

My goal is to filter out only the flow rate between 1pm and 7pm. As you can see from the time intervals each minute has 3 readings, so manually doing it is going to take a long time. Is there a way of using VBA to delete all the rows not in the specified time period?

Thank you.

This is what the top answer's solution looks like after I have changed 0.541666667 to 0.54166666:

[image: This is what the top answer's solution looks like after I have changed 0.541666667 to 0.54166666]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, we can see from your profile that you have not taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) yet. I suggest you do so and take the time to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before coming back here and [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53489027/edit) to let us know what you've tried so far

Comment: Nowadays 'between' means a lot of things when actually it means that 13:00:00 and 19:00:00 won't be included. If you want them included use from 1 pm to 7 pm. You have probably created a helper column in which you had a formula that contained the time only and filtered it with Autofilter and then deleted the rows you didn't need. If so you should mention it in your question (which you can edit at any time). And the reason for the need of using VBA might be that you're tired of everyday almost manually deleting the rows. Also mention it and provide maybe some code or an Excel formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to understand how dates & time work in excel.

Although your column appears to be filled with just time stamps (due to the format you chose), the cell is actually accompanied by a date. If you look at the `Formula Bar` in your photo, you can see the date as well.

All dates can be converted into a corresponding number. The relationship between the two is `Date.Time` = `Integer.Decimal`. Each integer is unique to a calendar day (you can find the starting point by converting `0` to a date). Since the time is not unique (I.E. the clock will strike 1:00 PM every day) the decimal number repeats itself at the same time every day. A easy decimal/time conversion is `noon = .50`

---

With that being said we can solve your problem by

1. Drop the integer (date)
2. Convert `1:00 PM` & `7:00 PM` to their decimal counterpart (roughly `.541667` & `.791667` respectively)
3. Loop through your rows and extract the decimal. If the extracted decimal is not in-between the thresholds determined in step 2 then go to step 4.
4. Add that cell to a `Union` (Collection of cells) and delete the `Union` (unwanted rows) at the end

It's worth mentioning that you can extract the decimal (time) in a few ways. I am making use of the `INT` function which turns all values after the decimal to 0. You could also use `Split` OR a bunch of other methods (`Mid`, `Left`, `Right`, `Len`, `Search`, `Find`, *etc*)

---

*Tested and working fine*

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClockWorkOrange()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<- Update
Dim LRow As Long, r As Range, myRange As Range, DeleteMe As Range

LRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set myRange = ws.Range("B3:B" & LRow)

For Each r In myRange
    If (r.Value2 - Int(r.Value2)) < 0.541666667 Or (r.Value2 - Int(r.Value2)) > 0.791666667 Then
        If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteMe = Union(DeleteMe, r)
        Else
            Set DeleteMe = r
        End If
    End If
Next r

If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then DeleteMe.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice one. Your code deletes rows containing values between 19:00:00,000 and 13:00:00,001 that is including 13:00:00,000. For including both values you should change to 0.79166665, and for NOT including you should change to 0.54166666. If you wanted to achieve exactly the functionality you did, then I would appreciate some clarification.

Comment: I don't think the value needs to be changed. OPs stamps also have seconds so its prob rare that this matters. For when it does, OP can simply change `< & >` to `<= & >=` to get desired result

Comment: Thank you! Somehow changing < & > to <= & >= doesn't change the results, perhaps it is how the decimals are stored? I deleted the last digit which you rounded and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

In Date& Time format your first 2 characters are the hour. 13:00-18:59 is 1:00pm to 6:59pm. So just use a `=LEFT()` to extract the hour, then delete the row if the hour is between those two numbers. Should look something like below:

```
Sub TimeDelete()
rowcount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
For Each n In Range("B1:b" & rowcount)
    n = Left(n, 2)
        If n >=13 And <=18 Then EntireRow.Delete
        Else
        End If
Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: The first 2 characters are actually part of the date. For this to work you will need to extract the time (decimal) from the cell and then convert it to a different format where the integer = hour and decimal = min/seconds. More explanation in solution below